# Criteria generates SQL Query correctly but it does not return anything

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria, hibernate-criteria

A criteria is used to retrieve data from database. It generates SQL Query perfectly, which is tested on `mySql` separately and the records are loaded correctly;
However, when using `Criterial.list()` it gives me an empty list.

I have checked my DB connections, and they are all correct. What would have caused this problem?

---

**UPDATED**
Here is my code:

```
accCr = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TSESpotInvestorAccount.class, "acc");
accCr.setResultTransformer(DetachedCriteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
accCr.add(Restrictions.eq("exchangeDepositNo", filter.getBc()));
accCr.setProjection(Projections.id());
List accIds = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(accCr);
```

Comment: Yes, code is necessary.

Comment: Just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense:

```
accCr.setResultTransformer(DetachedCriteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

The above line says that the query is supposed to return entities (with, potentially, joined entities), and that Hibernate should return only distinct entities

```
accCr.setProjection(Projections.id());
```

The above line says that the query must only return one scalar column: the ID of the root entity.

If what you want is a list of IDs, then don't set the distinct root entity result transformer.

Comment: Yeah I know. It doesn't make any sense at all. Thanks for your tip, I'll remember that. But the problem is not this.

Comment: Then either the query actually returns something, or you're not querying the database you think, or you've not committed the data in MySQL, or the value returned by `filter.getBc()` is not the one you think it is. Try removing this criterion, then print what it contains. Beware of extra spaces or other invisible characters.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it appears that there are some extra characters at the end of `filter.getBc()`, and that caused the problem. However, I learned a good lesson about `DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY`.